# Setting muliple rows in postgres based on the set values of previous postgres rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm running postgres 9.4

I'm essentially updating an existing unorganized structure to a folder based organization.  Im auto-assigning an order number to each item for user reordering, but doing an initial setting of all of these values with  a 1 time use update statement.  However, It seems like SET is taking my subquery's from clause and not recreating it for each successive row that it sets.

Here's my query example:

```
UPDATE folder_items
SET order_number = 
(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(folder_items_2.order_number), 0) + 1
FROM folder_items AS folder_items_2
WHERE folder_items.parent_folder_id = folder_items_2.parent_folder_id
AND folder_items.folder_set_id = folder_items_2.folder_set_id
AND folder_items.id != folder_items_2.id);
```

With my initial table:

```
         | folder_id    | folder_set_id | order_number
row 1    | 1            | 1             | null
row 2    | 2            | 1             | null
row 3    | 3            | 2             | null
row 4    | 4            | 2             | null
row 5    | 5            | 2             | null
row 6    | 6            | 3             | null
```

when I run my query I get something like

```
         | folder_id    | folder_set_id | order_number
row 1    | 1            | 1             | 1
row 2    | 2            | 1             | 1
row 3    | 3            | 2             | 1
row 4    | 4            | 2             | 1
row 5    | 5            | 2             | 1
row 6    | 6            | 3             | 1
```

However, I want results that look like this:

```
         | folder_id    | folder_set_id | order_number
row 1    | 1            | 1             | 1
row 2    | 2            | 1             | 2
row 3    | 3            | 2             | 1
row 4    | 4            | 2             | 2
row 5    | 5            | 2             | 3
row 6    | 6            | 3             | 1
```

Is there a way to get these desired results?  Is the best way to do some sort of window function that counts how many in the same folder_set_id are underneath each row?

Comment: The problem is you think the update will be reflected instanly, but the true is only will be update when the query end, so every time you call it will see the original version.

Comment: I see!  Is there any way to enact my desired output?

Comment: Or do I have to do something like order them all numerically, and then subtract by the number of non-folder-set items in the window underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate the `ORDER_ID`, then update the table.

```
with new_order as (
      SELECT "folder_id", 
              row_number() over ( partition by "folder_set_id"
                                  order by "folder_id") as rn
      FROM Table1
)
UPDATE Table1 AS t
SET "order_number" = n.rn
FROM new_order AS n
WHERE t."folder_id" = n."folder_id";
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b9a0/1)**

**OUTPUT**

```
| row_id | folder_id | folder_set_id | order_number |
|--------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
|  row 1 |         1 |             1 |            1 |
|  row 2 |         2 |             1 |            2 |
|  row 3 |         3 |             2 |            1 |
|  row 4 |         4 |             2 |            2 |
|  row 5 |         5 |             2 |            3 |
|  row 6 |         6 |             3 |            1 |
```